How chord functions using minor subdominant

I'm reading this part of arnold shoenbrg harmony book ( minor subdominant )
And i don't know if the chords are supposed to function at all or it's just the matter of voice leading  and taste '
For example if i'm using Ab and D° in C major ( using two chords from C minor ) should i read this as VI - II° ) in c minor and maybe put a G7 after but end on C major  ?
But it could also function as ( III and raised VI) in F minor
I have this idea that chords should  function as they were in the original form in the main key
For exmaple Fm -Ab - G7  functions same as F -Am -G7 in ( C major )
I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me


Please add commas, full stops and capital letters to your post, as needed. It's difficult to read as it is. 2. Are you referring to a specific example in the attached score? If so, could you indicate which measures exactly? I somehow cannot find a sequence Ab-Do in there. The answer to your question may depend on the context/surrounding chords.


I just imported a picture to show the subject i'm talking about . It's a really big topic so i don't think anyone who could've help me needed more information than the chord progression i mentioned( so as the other friend said it's related to if i use the in a balanced way that the tonality  in tonic is not lost )

Okay i will fix the text . thanks

"i don't think anyone who could've help me needed more information than the chord progression i mentioned": the chord progression you mentioned isn't shown in the image, however, so the question is confusing.  "so as the other friend said it's related to if i use the in a balanced way that the tonality in tonic is not lost": there seems to be a noun missing between "use the" and "in a balanced way."

I was gonna edit that comment but i had to wait 5 minutes :(   the missing word is the nondiatonic chords from the minor subdominant ( borrowed chords)


...I have this idea that chords should be function as they were in the original form in the main key For exmaple Fm -Ab - G7 functions same as F -Am -G7 in ( C major ) I would appreciate if anyone could enlighten me

With Roman numeral analysis...


    Fm   Ab   G7
Cm: iv   VI   V7
C:  iv  ♭VI   V7

    F    Am  G7
Cm: IV  ♮vi  V7
C:  IV   vi  V7

Notice the scale degree/root numbering does not change, all are 4 6 5.
Notice the case of the Roman numerals does not change, because the chord qualities do not change regardless of whatever key you may choose for analysis.
Notice that the accidentals do not change the roots of the chords, they only make clear whether the given chord root is diatonic to the key signature or is altered.
In other words, as long as the tonic is considered C, it doesn't change the analysis of the chords. At most you add accidentals for clarity.
If you describe those chords with scale degree functional labels only, it will be "subdominant, submediant, dominant." In broader functional terms it is just "two pre-dominant chords followed by a dominant chord." Again, as long as it's clear the tonic is C the variations in mode don't change the description of the functional harmony.
The general idea is that when working with borrowed chords, the functional working of a passage doesn't change as a result of swapping out with borrowed chords.

...Ab and D° in C major ( using two chords from C minor ) should i read this as VI - II° ) in c minor...But it could also be ( III and raised VI) in F minor


     Ab  D°
C:  ♭VI  ii°

Fm: III ♮vi°

Well, maybe. But you have neither the dominant nor tonic which makes things tricky for definitively identifying the key.
For a moments let's use Roman numerals in all caps without reference to chord quality or altered roots (this is how many older harmony textbooks use Roman numeral analysis.) Our choices then are C: VI II or Fm: III VI. One way to look at it is how close one or the other is to primary harmonies IV V I or the modal harmonies III VI II. All things being equal, in an ambiguous case like this, you might go with the analysis that is closer to primary harmonies rather than modal harmonies. So, the choice is C: VI II, C: ♭VI ii° if you want the specific qualities labeled. Otherwise, you really need to fill in harmonies either before or after sufficient to make a tonic/dominant, key-defining relationship clear.

It's such a clear explanation .so  Eventually it comes to what comes next and before if we stay too long in the minor subdominant key the tonality is lost and we have a modulation

@user98606 another point that might be added to this answer: ambiguity of this sort often functions as a "pivot" to a related key.  So it wouldn't be surprising to see a progression like this between a passage where F is the tonal center and one where C is the tonal center, or vice versa.

Ab and D° in C major are just used as they were in c minor (but be careful of the voice leading), so do any chord from the relative minor and any altered chords, unless they contain the lowered iv degree(does not work in major + must lead to minor tonic) or the raised ii degree(does not work in minor + must lead to major tonic).
for example with C major as tonic, Ab resolves to G, F to E, C carries over, Db to C, and D# to E.
a: t - dtIII - D7 - tsVI - D43/s - s - K64 - DDvii7 - K64 - D7 - t
b: T - tsVI - ii65 - DD - D - dtIII - vii7/s - s - vii65 - t6 - ii65 - D7 - T
c: T - vii7/tsVI - tsVI - s6 - t - DDvii7 - D - dtIII - vii7/s - s6 - DD - D - T
dtIII is mediant of parallel minor, tsVI is submediant of parallel minor, K64 is cadential 6-4 (major or minor), ii is supertonic of parallel minor and, II is supertonic from of parallel major
note that diminished ii7 is a form of the minor subdominant and c minor functions are used. (the shorthand means that the chord is made up tones from minor or major versions of tonic, subdominant, and/or dominant). a modulation has to have a clear pattern and a key change must end at a perfect cadence.
